# Spark csv databricks remove the trailing spaces in each line

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe which has only one column and I am writing that dataframe into a HDFS location using databricks csv

There are some trailing spaces in each line and I want those spaces to be included when that dataframe gets stored

My spark version is 1.5 CDH 5.5

I am running the spark job as below

```
 spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.1.0 


df.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(path)

Trailing spaces are included when the above write happens but each line has quotes and start of that line and end of that line
```

so I tried the below

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quote","\u0000").save(path)

starting quotes and ending quotes are removed and the trailing spaces are also removed
```

so I tried the below

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","false").option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false").option("quote","\u0000").save(path)

No impact . 
starting quotes and ending quotes are removed and the trailing spaces are also removed
```

I dont want quotes to be stored , but I want traling spaces

How do I achieve that?